# How to generate a Menu of Modules Backend with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm working on a old project! The backend was generate normally and there is a menu. Now I want to add some modules and then to reduce the space taking by all the modules links, generate a menu with submenu. A submenu can be a collection of modules links or just a module link.

How can I generate it with symfony?

Is there a way to customize the backend menu in symfony?

Comment: Have you checked if it's a plugin or a component or what ever that generate this menu?

Comment: the Menu was generated like the tutorial (http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/12) show... so a basic Menu!

Comment: You're talking about `Jobs` and `Categories` in the `div#menu` ? It's just html, there is not built-in backend menu in Symfony.

Comment: Oh! okay i think i must delete this post isnt? Thanks!

Comment: @trouble you can use **[sfAdminDashPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfAdminDashPlugin)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about symfony 1.4?!
The only way I know is to generate all the modules you need, and then to manually create the links, menu and submenu with the HTML code and JS you need.